# What is the regex pattern to match a Zambian NRC number

Tags: regex

Zambian National Registration Numbers(NRC) follow a pattern of 6 digits followed by a forward slash, followed by 2 digits, then another forward slash and then 1 digit at the end. An example of an NRC number would be 111111/11/1.

What regular expression can I use to match this format of numbers and slashes.

Answer (score 1):

This format should work `^\d{6}\/\d{2}\/\d{1}$`

`^` - means match at the start of the string

`\d{6}` - means match exactly 6 digits

`\/` - means match the forward slash.

`\d{2}` - means match exactly 2 digits

`\d{1}` - means match exactly 1 digit

`$` - means match at the end of the string

You can test the regex expression on this site: https://regex101.com/

Comment: forward slash is not special character and doesn't need to be escaped. Also the `{1}` is not necessary as it is the default of every character in a regex: https://regex101.com/r/BKnuAl/2

Comment: @Tomerikoo In some languages, Forward slash will close the pattern

Comment: Thanks for noting that @Tomerikoo. Its not a special character. But in JavaScript it might need to be escaped. https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping

Comment: Oh sorry I was automatically considering Python (as I am used to use that) and didn't notice it's a general regex question

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\(?([0-9]{6})\)?\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{1})$/
```

This should work too

Comment: There might be an issue with the format for this one. It didnt work for me. Could you try checking if its valid using a website such as https://regex101.com/

Comment: Did you mean this? `^(([0-9]{6}))\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{1})$`. It works, but it looks very similar to the other answer

Answer (score 0):

and this also, and is the more portable solution:

```
^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]$
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of zambian NRC is [ , 6 digits between 0 and 9 ] / [, 2 digits between 0 and 9] / [, 1 which can either be 1 for zambian or 2 for a non zambian ]

therefore any derivative of the following should work:

1. ^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[1-2]